# Transition on D3 sunburst pie based on searched name

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am making use of the Zoomable Sunburst on d3.js v4 here: https://bl.ocks.org/maybelinot/5552606564ef37b5de7e47ed2b7dc099

It works great but now I added a search engine that looks for the names of the pie's parents and childrens. I am capturing the name and find it in the pie, but I am trying now to make it zoom-in/transition to the selected arc based on the name searched. 
In its default set-up it zooms in and out based on the click, but I would like to change it to zoom-in to the element/arc typed in the search engine.
Till now I have only made it to change the opacity based on the selected arc based on its name searched:

```
$( ".searchbutton" ).click(function() {
    var tc = $(this).closest("form").find("input[type='search']").val();
    console.log(tc)   
    svg.selectAll("path")[0].forEach(function (d) {
      if (d3.select(d).data()[0].name == tc) {
          d3.select(d).style("opacity", 1);
      } else {
        d3.select(d).style("opacity", 0.1);
      }
    }) 
});
```

Any ideas how to achieve this? Should I search the arc by name and use programmatically click on the bounding coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you mean. Just get the data and filter it by the name. You can get a filtered array and call the click function with this data

[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vgLyxrxn/)

```
$("#input").on('input', function(e){
    let val = $(e.currentTarget).val()
    console.log(svg.selectAll("path").data())
   let filter =  svg.selectAll("path").data().filter((el) => {
   return el.data.name == val})
   if(filter.length == 1){
        click(filter[0])
   }

});
```